# Changing a UINavigationController's RootViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I've seen the post about how to do this here [Changing a UINavigationController’s Root View Controller](http://starterstep.wordpress.com/2009/03/05/changing-a-uinavigationcontroller%E2%80%99s-root-view-controller/) And various other posts on SO. But...

I've implemented a different solution which seems rather more simple, however I was wondering if there's something massively flawed about this approach since I haven't seen it used or described elsewhere and my confidence in my own code isn't very high. I also think my approach may be the cause of another issue which I'll mention at the end.

My appDelegate has a UINavigationController variable called navController. When the game loads, I check for saved data. If it exists, I initialise the navController with the game's main view as the rootViewController. If none exists, I initialise the navController to the menu rootViewController and load that instead. If the user goes from the menu to the game, or from the game to the menu, I initialise a new rootViewController and set it to the appDelegate's navController variable, then display it. Here is the code in my appDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[self dataFilePath]]) { 
        self.saveDataExists = TRUE;
        GameViewController *gameViewController = [[GameViewController alloc] init]; 
        UINavigationController *gameNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:gameViewController];
        [gameViewController release];
        self.navController = gameNavController;
        [gameNavController release]; 
    }
    else {
        self.saveDataExists = FALSE;
        MainMenuViewController *mainMenuViewController = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *menuNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainMenuViewController];
        [mainMenuViewController release];
        self.navController = menuNavController;
        [menuNavController release];
    }

[fileManager release];
    [window addSubview:navController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Here is the code when the user goes from the menu to the game:

```
// Initialise the new Root Controller
GameViewController *rootController = [[GameViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *newNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
[rootController release];   
newNavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:newNavController animated:YES];

//Setting the appDelegate's navController to the new navController allows the menu to dealloc. 
//This must happen AFTER the newNavController has been loaded. 
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
appDelegate.navController = newNavController;
[newNavController release];
```

And from the game to the menu:

```
MainMenuViewController *menuViewController = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] init]; 
UINavigationController *newNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuViewController];
[menuViewController release];
newNavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:newNavController animated:YES];

//Setting the appDelegate's navController to the new navController allows the menu to dealloc. 
//This must happen AFTER the newNavController has been loaded.  
self.appDelegate.navController = newNavController;
[newNavController release];
```

It seems to work fine, there are no memory leaks and the transition is quick. But I have this niggling sense that it's wrong. I've left it for over a year, but recently I've been integrating the HeyZap SDK (a gaming social network where users 'check in' to a game). Logging in to HeyZap loads the HeyZap app, and then returns to the game via a URL scheme you define. If I load HeyZap from my game's menu, it returns to the game just fine. However if I load HeyZap from the game, it crashes on return (with no error output). I'm wondering if this might be because the app is confused as to which RootVC it's loading. But normally I can switch between apps just fine... I have two URL schemes - one for Facebook, and the other for HeyZap, and they look like this:

[image: info plist file]

Any advice much appreciated! Thanks, Michael.

Comment: I think you have forgotten the code that `initialise a new RootVC and set it to [your] appDelegate's UINavigationController instance`. also, you should post your code handling the URL scheme to see if the crash is related to a VC present in your MenuNavController but not in your GameNavController.

Comment: Thanks - I've updated my question. I don't actually use any code to handle the URL scheme, I just added it as per the instructions in HeyZap and assumed that was enough?

Comment: I suspect the crash might be related to returning from background state. Does the crash also occur when you open your app, then go into the game, then close the app, then reopen it? Does your AppDelegate do anything in applicationDidBecomeActive: or applicationWillEnterForeground:?

Comment: No the app usually returns perfectly fine from background state, it's only when returning from HeyZap... I do do stuff in  both applicationDidBecomeActive and WillEnterForeground but I don't think either do anything that would effect the crash...

Comment: if the app crashes when loading HeyZap from the game, maybe it's because you are calling a method of the rootViewController of your navigationController, which exists in the MainMenuViewController but not in the GameViewController.

Comment: btw, you can refactor your first piece of code. and why do you use `presentModalViewController` on the replacing navigationController ?

Comment: No the app crashes on return from the HeyZap app. And the method to launch HeyZap exists in both controllers anyway. What do you mean when you say refactor the first piece of code? I use presentModalViewController so that I can use the horizontal flip animation... What else would I use? It's a new rootViewController so I shouldn't push it onto the stack.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error when running from XCode (on device), and add an Exception breakpoint? Then you should get some information where the crash occurs.